# How do I do "group by" and yet also get the sum?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table thats kinda like this...

```
    A    B
    1    1
    1    1
    1    2
    2    2
    2    2
    2    1
```

I used the mysql query

```
select A, B from myTable group by A, B
```

to get it to look like this...

```
    A    B
    1    1
    1    2
    2    2
    2    1
```

Now I want to get the sum of "A" column. I tried using

```
select sum(A) from myTable group by A, B
```

but it doesn't work as the "group by" command ruins the result. (I want to get 6)

How would i go about this?

EDIT:
Because it wasn't clear, i want the output to look like this

```
    A
    6
```

the 6 is from (1+1+2+2) in the A column

Comment: What exactly would be your desired result? It's not clear to me what format you want the output in, and what values you want included.

Comment: `select A, B from myTable group by A, B` does not really make any sense. Why are you grouping if you are not using any aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the sum of A for all distinct combinations of A,B, you can use a simple subquery;

```
SELECT SUM(A) A FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT A,B
  FROM mytable
)z;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d208/1)

Comment: I agree that this provides the correct answer, and satisfies the brief. I'm left wondering if the original specification was inadequate.